# Why CasperJS doesn't load images?

Tags: javascript, php, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

Try to scrap some info from this web page:
[link](http://www.lamoda.by/c/369/clothes-platiya/?genders=women&sitelink=topmenuW&l=3)

I'm using PhantomJS/CasperJs, but unfortunately, have no enough knowledge or experience to understand why some things go wrong.

The task is to scrap info from parent ".products-catalog__list" container with text info and also images, but the result of my (written below) code is not like I wish. 
Casper displays images only of first 4 children containers. I thought that the problem is in time that Casper loads the page, tried to set timeout function, but without any chance)

My code is too simple at start:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)');

link = 'http://www.lamoda.by/c/369/clothes-platiya/?genders=women&sitelink=topmenuW&l=3';

casper.start();

casper.thenOpen(link, function() {
  this.waitForSelector('.products-catalog__list', function() {
    this.echo(this.getHTML('.products-catalog__list'));
  });
});

casper.run();
```

Launch this script with the help of PHP shell_exec.

Comment: I haven't looked at the page, but it is common now to only load further images when they are scrolled into view, so you probably have to scroll the page. Let me know if the following two answers help: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33805294/1816580) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28927464/1816580)

Comment: @ArtjomB. sorry for my such quickly conclusions, you are absolutely right, content loads when it is scrolled into view, thank you for some useful links, will learn it)

Comment: @ArtjomB. one more question inside this theme) page, i'm working with, execute js too strange... For example, main dropdown doesn't work) Generally all js hover effects don't work)) Thank you!

Comment: So, did you try to use `mouseover` and `mousemove` with `casper.mouseEvent`?

Comment: @ArtjomB. can you, please, look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38011752/how-to-get-dynamic-content-with-phantomjs-casperjs?noredirect=1#comment63501977_38011752

I really need your help, thank you!