# How to properly hover the mouse over an element in PhantomJS/CasperJS

Tags: javascript, hover, phantomjs, casperjs, slimerjs

In my opinion, a problem of getting dynamic content is really very ambiguous. I tried to find some useful information, used many different code examples, certainly modifying them to my purposes, but unfortunately, without any results(

I need to get some contents from [here](http://www.lamoda.ru). Try to explain detailed what are the problems i faced to (need to notice, that all i do is exclusively for my own use!).

Main web site page has main navigation ([Main nav pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s9s5.png)) list with each list class "menu__category-trigger". Every "menu__category-trigger" has each own dropdown menu container. All these dropdown menu containers have parent wrapper with class "menu__categories-dropdowns". When main page is loaded "menu__categories-dropdowns" is empty, there is no any dropdown menu container there. But when i hover on any "menu__category-trigger", all "menu__categories-dropdowns" appear and stay on page until its reload.

I need to get this content with the help of PhantomJS/CasperJS, but i can't understand how to do that. My code is:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'error',
    pageSettings: {
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4',
    },
    viewportSize: {
        width: 1440,
        height: 5000
    }
});

var url = 'http://www.lamoda.ru/women-home/';

var links = []; 

function getLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('.menu__column a');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        return e.getAttribute('data-link');
    })
};

casper.start(url, function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
    this.echo("Got title");
});

casper.wait(2000, function() {
    this.echo("I have waited for two seconds...");
});

casper.then( function() {
    this.mouse.click('.popup__close'); // Doing screenshot of the page, i saw that sometimes a popup appears and blocks a possibility of hovering "menu__category-trigger"
    this.echo("Popup closed");
});

casper.waitForSelector('.menu__categories-dropdowns', function(){ // main dropdowns container
    console.log('Dropdown selector is loaded');
});

casper.then( function() {
    casper.page.injectJs('./jquery-2.0.3.min.js');
    this.evaluate(function () {
        //$('body').attr('class', 'not-touch').addClass('user-unauthorized');
        $('.menu__category-trigger').hover( function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('menu__category-trigger_active'); // On original page hovering ".menu__category-trigger" adds it additional class ".menu__category-trigger_active" with the appearance of dropdowns
        });
     });
    this.mouse.down('.menu__category-trigger:nth-of-type(2)'); // Hover on some navigation div
    console.log('Injected JS, Nav item hovered');
});

casper.wait(5000, function() {
    this.echo("I have waited for five seconds..."); // THE MAIN "WAIT" FUNCTION, i try to wait for each dropdown after hovering my navigation div (".menu__category-trigger"), but without any result
});

casper.then( function() {
    this.capture('google.jpg', {
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: 1440,
        height: 5000
    });
    console.log('Screenshot done'); // On made screenshot i see that mouse is really moved on ".menu__category-trigger:nth-of-type(2)", because it changed its text color like on original page
});

casper.then( function() {
    this.echo(this.getPageContent());
    links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
});

casper.then( function() {
    this.echo(links.length + ' links found:');
    this.echo('-' + links.join('\n -')).exit() ;
});

casper.run();
```

My each step is registered in code)

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again?  What happened with my suggestion to move the mouse via Casperjs to the element so the dynamic content loads?

Comment: @fatfantasma, your advice was good enough, i use casperjs mouse module, and even can track that: element i hover, changes its color like it does when you hover this element on original page... The problem is deeper, i think, that's why i really hope somebody will try to get needed info himself) Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to explain your exact problem better.  It's not clear what you want.

Comment: @fatfantasma, updated my question, now you can see that i've tried use your advise, but, in my opinion, the problem is more difficult, that's why i need your help. Thanks!

Comment: I've no idea why it doesn't work, but you could just request the data yourself. Through `__utils__.sendAJAX()` from the page context and put it where it needs to go in the page, which will automatically parse it.

Comment: @ArtjomB., can you please give some examples how to do that

Comment: What result are you getting?  Where is getLinks defined? I also don't think "links" is global and can't be used between steps as it is coded now.

Comment: Sry.  I see your getLinks function now.  I am viewing your code on my phone and missed it.

Comment: @ArtjomB., you was right about necessity of sending ajax request. When i click "menu__category-trigger" on original page, page sends ajax request (http://www.lamoda.ru/_blocks/menu/?genders=women&ajax=1). But after sending a request i always get NULL...

Comment: @ArtjomB., My steps are unaltered. Ajax request i send like in example on casper docs page. Tried even with web-secure=no. 

Thank you!

Comment: The problem is that this request is not even sent to the server (I've checked with `casper.on("resource.requested", fn)` and Wireshark).

Comment: @ArtjomB. And is there any solution, any possibility to send this request?! Why doesn't it send?(

Comment: Request is exactly correct, may the problem be in cookies?

Comment: @ArtjomB. May I count on your any assumptions?)) I've no any ideas(

Comment: I don't know why the request isn't sent to the server and I don't know why no error is shown, but you can certainly do a workaround by executing `this.evaluate(function(){ document.querySelector('.menu__categories-dropdowns').innerHTML = __utils__.sendAJAX('http://www.lamoda.ru/_blocks/menu/?genders=women&ajax=1', 'GET'); })` just before calling `links = this.evaluate(getLinks);`